# How does a partially covered air intake affect the thrust of a propeller ?

Tags: jet-engine, propeller, turbofan, engine-design, propulsion

does a partially covered air intake of a ducted propeller significantly affect its thrust?
If so, will it be like 10 or rather 90 percent less thrust ?

[image]

Thanks for your answers!

Simon

Comment: This may mostly depend on relative wind speed and direction.

Comment: It certainly would.  You've introduced an inlet restriction as well as a lot of turbulence to the flow.

Comment: A full discussion would involve fluid dynamics and might be too broad (although Peter Kampf has a habit of condensing stuff like that nicely) however if would be extremely helpful for you to give an/some examples to narrow the scope.